risk parity portfolio from scenario optimization
would like to ask how we could use simulated asset returns (a matrix $R\in\mathbb{R}^{s\times d}$ from scenarios, row per sample and col per asset) to construct a risk parity portfolio (RPP).
by definition, RPP minimize the std.dev.(variance) of derivative of portfolio return std.dev.(variance) w.r.t. asset weights
$$
\underset{\mathbf{w}}{\min} \mathbb{V}_d[
\frac{\partial \sqrt{(\mathbb{V}_s[\mathbf{R}\mathbf{w}])}}{\partial \mathbf{w}}
]
$$
where $\mathbf{w}$ is a col vector of portfolio weights,
$\sqrt{\mathbb{V}_s[\mathbf{Rw}]}$ is std.dev. of portfolio returns in sampled scenarios, the external $\mathbb{V}_d$ is the std.dev. of derivatives (w.r.t. portfolio weights); overall this objective function aims to let each weight contribute equally towards risk in various scenarios.
the objective function is:
R = MatrixSymbol["R", {s, d}, Reals];
w  = VectorSymbol["w", d, Reals];
StandardDeviation[D[StandardDeviation[R . w], w]] // Normal // 
  Rationalize // FullSimplify


1.
is this objective function convex? what are suitable optimization algorithms? SGD/ADAM/etc.?
2.
For application we may further add regularization terms to let weights be penalized for transaction cost and benchmarked upon, for example, equal weight (Talmud):
$$
\underset{\mathbf{w}}{\min} \mathbb{V}_d[
\frac{\partial \sqrt{(\mathbb{V}_s[\mathbf{R}\mathbf{w}])}}{\partial \mathbf{w}}
]
+
c\|\mathbf{w}-\mathbf{w}_0\|_1
+
\lambda\|\mathbf{w}-\frac{1}{d}\|_1
$$
here $c$ is transaction cost (0.0015), $\mathbf{w}_0$ as portfolio weights prior to rebalancing, $\lambda=0.001$ a regularization constant, and $\frac{1}{d}$ as the equal weight.
would those 1-norm affect convexity? what are suitable optimization algorithms in this case?
3.
since we can use the "classical" risk parity from the least square (from wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risk_parity), using covmat from scenario simulated returns directly, say the solution is $\mathbf{w}_{rp}$
$$
{\displaystyle {\underset {w}{\arg \min }}\sum _{i=1}^{N}\left[w_{i}-{\frac {\sigma (w)^{2}}{(\Sigma w)_{i}N}}\right]^{2}}
$$
can we merge those into one obj fun to reach a trade-off among transaction cost, risk-parity style, and equal weight style?
$$
\underset{\mathbf{w}}{\min} 
~
c\|\mathbf{w}-\mathbf{w}_0\|_1
+
\lambda_1\|\mathbf{w}-\mathbf{w}_{rp}\|_1
+
\lambda_2\|\mathbf{w}-\frac{1}{d}\|_1
$$

Seems like a very tough problem )-:

Have you looked at the other risk parity questions asked in QSE?

hi @nbbo2 indeed it looks not straight forward at first glance, but i'm just curious if the objfun is still convex; or we should resort to certain type of solvers.

hi @KaiSqDist I checked and most of them begin with the covmat to aim for the least square objfun; now we have a detailed asset return forecast R and would like to work towards the definition "equal risk contribution" directly.

I cannot say that I understand the notation you use. But for "classical" risk parity, a.k.a. equal-risk contribution, using scenarios does not really change the computation. You can  calculate the variance-covariance matrix of the columns of the scenario matrix and use it for selecting the portfolio. It would be different if you used a non-standard risk measure, which does not aggregate the information in the scenarios, as the standard deviation does.

Mr. Schumann, you should consider re-using the above comment as an answer to the question.

Hi @EnricoSchumann, Thank you for your insightful comments. I've updated the notations as per your suggestions. Would like to consult your experience or view on the non-standard risk measure part, as in practice we have to account for transaction costs and style mandates in conjunction with a standard classical objective function. I would appreciate your thoughts on how best to approach this, particularly any strategies or frameworks you’ve found effective.

Expanding my comment on non-standard risk measures:
under risk parity/ERC, you look at the marginal
contributions to risk, which means the first
derivatives of a function $f$ that maps weights (and
data) into a single number, the risk.  If $f$ is the
standard deviation, it can be conveniently and
efficiently computed from the covariance matrix.  But
after all, you look for first derivatives, which you
can approximate by finite differences.  The downside,
of course, is a higher computational cost, but there
might be no other alternative way to compute those contributions, and you gain flexibility.  Specifically, if $R$ is
the returns matrix, and $w$ are the weights, then the
$i$-th weight's derivative can be approximated as
$(f(R(w^*_i)) - f(Rw))/ h$. The symbol $h$ is a small
number: for a forward difference, as here, typically of
the order of $10^{-8}$ or similar; when in doubt, use a
larger number. $w^*_i$ is the weights vector with the
$i$-th weight increased by $h$.
Computational 'proof': I use R to simulate 20 return
scenarios for 5 assets.
library("FRAPO")  ## for function 'mrc'
library("NMOF")   ## for function 'randomReturns'

na <- 5
R <- randomReturns(na = na, ns = 20, sd = 0.02, rho = 0.5)
##          [,1]    [,2]    [,3]    [,4]   [,5]
##  [1,]  0.0381  0.0320  0.0126  0.0161  0.015
##  [2,]  0.0117  0.0028  0.0367 -0.0100 -0.004
##  [3,] -0.0258 -0.0006 -0.0124  0.0017 -0.005
##  [4,]  0.0309  0.0182  0.0064  0.0197  0.014
##  [5,] -0.0202 -0.0259 -0.0457  0.0064 -0.023
##  [6,] -0.0036  0.0018 -0.0345 -0.0149 -0.019
## ....


## equal-weight portfolio
w <- rep(1/na, na)


## risk function: input is a vector of _portfolio_
## returns under the scenarios
risk <- function(Rw, ...) {
    sqrt(var(c(Rw)))
}

risk(R %*% w)
## [1] 0.01432615   ## vol of the equal-weight portfolio

The function mrc_fd implements the above formula for a finite difference:
## approximate first-derivatives of risk with respect
## to weights via forward difference
mrc_fd <- function(w, R, risk, ..., h = 1e-8) {
    Rw <- R %*% w
    dR <- R*h

    ans <- numeric(length(w))
    for (i in seq_along(w)) {    
        ans[i] <- w[i] * ( risk(Rw + dR[, i]) - risk(Rw) ) / h
    }
    ans
}

Compare the results with the implementation of marginal risk contribution in package FRAPO:
FRAPO::mrc(w, var(R), FALSE)
## [1] 0.00301 0.00200 0.00349 0.00240 0.00343

mrc_fd(w = w, R = R, risk = risk)
## [1] 0.00301 0.00200 0.00349 0.00240 0.00343

The numbers are the same. But where mrc computes them off the covariance matrix, function mrc_fd directly works with the scenarios, and so would work with other definitions of risk as well.
Concerning methods: I like local-search methods, which
(like scenario optimization) are extremely
flexible. Essentially, these method start with random
solution, and then iteratively change this solution by
increasing/decreasing weights in small steps, until
they have arrived at a good solution (or some computational limit is reached, such as a fixed number of iterations).  Threshold
Accepting (TA), for instance, is such a method, and it
is also implemented in the NMOF package.  TA is also an
early, perhaps the earliest derivative-free method that
was used for portfolio selection, as described in
@ARTICLE{Dueck1992,
  author       = {Gunter Dueck and Peter Winker},
  title        = {New Concepts and Algorithms for Portfolio Choice},
  journal      = {Applied Stochastic Models and Data Analysis},
  year         = 1992,
  volume       = 8,
  pages        = {159--178},
  number       = 3
}

(Disclosure: I am the maintainer of package NMOF.)
